# Can we have listener in AsyncStorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I am using `AsyncStorage` to store some values frequently and I want to display the values on the screen. I am using `useffect()` to read all the values and print them. It works fine for the first time, but from next time onwards new values are not gettings displayed. Can I implement an event listener so that I can keep refreshing the value displayed on the screen?

```
     const [view, setview] = useState('');
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
          fromasyncstorage();
        }, []),
      );
    
     const fromasyncstorage = async () => {
        const valuex = await AsyncStorage.getItem('message');
        if (valuex) {
          setview(valuex);
        }
      };
    //setview is used to display the message on screen

return(
<View>

<Text>{view}</Text>
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be achieved by adding an abstraction on top of the storage.
Please refer to the link for more description: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/401

Comment: @userrr They didn't complain about the code while the discussion was open

Comment: yes, i think i made a mistake in converting that to fuinctional component could you help me convert it to functional component ?@Reza Shafie

Comment: In what part are you stuck? @userrr

Comment: how do i implement this solution in my code above some pointers would be good !!